# VBA Copay values from one Workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I need vba code, to do the following:

Choose a randomly named workbook, holding specific sheet named "ImportData", copy the values in Column A1:T121. If there is data in column "K" and the Column "E" is not blank.

Paste the values into MainWorkbook sheet 1, on the first empty row in column A.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code and try:

```
Option Explicit

 Sub test()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long

    'Make sure that both workbooks are open
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")

    'Refer to Book1 & Sheet1
    With wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Get the last row of Book1, Sheet1 & column A
         Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            'Loops Book1, Sheet1 & column A from line 1 to lastrow
            For i = 1 To Lastrow
                'Check for blanks in colums E & K
                If .Range("E" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("K" & i).Value <> "" Then
                    'If there are no blanks copy from wb1, Sheet1 & Range "A1:D1" to wb2, Sheet1 & Range "A1:D1"
                    .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D1").Copy wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D1")
                End If
            Next i

    End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the help. Let me try to be more specific. The file I need to copy from will not be open, so I would like to choose this file from Fileexplorer using this line of code as well "    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)"

Comment: As you can see i have provide guidelines. It s better to start coding and if you face any issue ask for help with your piece of code.